# Python regexp module re

Tags: python, regex

Is there any change to put **"Customer-01"** and **"Cust-02"** to the last column(with python regexp) like in "**Expected output section**" below?

**Example:**

```
Customer-01
192.168.12.100  61212 10    18w3d    00:00:37 00:00:22
192.168.12.120  61212 337   6d00h    00:00:07 00:00:06
192.168.12.130  61212 0     1w3d     00:00:42 00:00:54
192.168.12.140  61212 0     36w6d    00:00:14 00:00:22
192.168.12.150  61212 4     11w3d    00:00:24 00:00:22


Cust-02         
192.168.13.100  61212 10    18w3d    00:00:37 00:00:22
192.168.14.120  61212 337   6d00h    00:00:07 00:00:06
192.168.15.130  61212 0     1w3d     00:00:42 00:00:54
192.168.16.140  61212 0     36w6d    00:00:14 00:00:22
192.168.17.150  61212 4     11w3d    00:00:24 00:00:22
```

**Expected output:**

```
192.168.12.100  61212 10    18w3d    00:00:37 00:00:22 Customer-01
192.168.12.120  61212 337   6d00h    00:00:07 00:00:06 Customer-01
192.168.12.130  61212 0     1w3d     00:00:42 00:00:54 Customer-01
192.168.12.140  61212 0     36w6d    00:00:14 00:00:22 Customer-01
192.168.12.150  61212 4     11w3d    00:00:24 00:00:22 Customer-01


192.168.13.100  61212 10    18w3d    00:00:37 00:00:22 Cust-02  
192.168.14.120  61212 337   6d00h    00:00:07 00:00:06 Cust-02
192.168.15.130  61212 0     1w3d     00:00:42 00:00:54 Cust-02
192.168.16.140  61212 0     36w6d    00:00:14 00:00:22 Cust-02
192.168.17.150  61212 4     11w3d    00:00:24 00:00:22 Cust-02
```

Comment: Im sorry, I do not understand your question. What are these examples suppose to be? text files?

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this with a regex.

1. Split text into blocks by double line break
2. Put line[0] at end of line [1] to line[n] of each block

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Adjust text according to example."""


def adjust_text(text):
    blocks = text.split("\n\n\n")
    for block_nr, block in enumerate(blocks):
        lines = block.split("\n")
        for line_nr, _ in enumerate(lines):
            if line_nr != 0:
                lines[line_nr] += "  " + lines[0]
        blocks[block_nr] = "\n".join(lines)

    text = "\n\n\n".join(blocks)
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = """Customer-01
192.168.12.100  60000 10    18w3d    00:00:37 00:00:22 E  179/34634  9/1
192.168.12.120  64524 337   6d00h    00:00:07 00:00:06 E  179/29837  0/0
192.168.12.130  64522 0     1w3d     00:00:42 00:00:54 E  9835/179   0/0
192.168.12.140  64512 0     36w6d    00:00:14 00:00:22 E  33883/179  0/0
192.168.12.150  64512 4     11w3d    00:00:24 00:00:22 E  179/13712  4/0


Cust-02
192.168.13.100  64512 10    18w3d    00:00:37 00:00:22 E  179/34634  9/1
192.168.14.120  64524 337   6d00h    00:00:07 00:00:06 E  179/29837  0/0
192.168.15.130  64522 0     1w3d     00:00:42 00:00:54 E  9835/179   0/0
192.168.16.140  64512 0     36w6d    00:00:14 00:00:22 E  33883/179  0/0
192.168.17.150  64512 4     11w3d    00:00:24 00:00:22 E  179/13712  4/0"""
    text = adjust_text(text)
    print(text)
```

Comment: Can this be done with Python? I want to output those columns on HTML Table tags.

Comment: Sure it can be done with Python. I could write it in about 10 seconds if I wasn't on mobile

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by HTML table tags. I can't see any HTML table tags in your expected output

Comment: i want to to put one value from the first column between html tags table:
<td>192.168.12.100 </td>

Comment: @MartinThoma You need a little bluetooth keyboard :D

Comment: @kame I actually have one for exactly this reason  since I moved I can't find it anymore

Comment: @petrisor I don't see that in your expected output. If you can't figure out what you want, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: First of all i need to add that title "Customer-01" and "Cust-02" to last column as I showed in Expected Output. Can I do that with python?